# ASP window.open file ODT

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net, iis, odt

I have some problems with a function window.open('url').
My variable "url" focus on a ODT file and when i try to open this file with a web browser (http://localhost//../test.odt), I have "HTTP 404 PAGE NOT FOUND".

I have already tried with diferent extentions : png, pdf, docx, etc. and it's work.

For information : the file is uploaded on a local repertory.Is the problem could be the MIME content or something else ?

Thanks you

Comment: You would need to add the mime type to IIS for this to work otherwise IIS gives a 404 for unknown extensions. https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc725608(v=ws.10).aspx

Comment: thanks for your answer, I have solved the problem !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your website in IIS don't have configured MIME type for .odt files. Correct mimetype is:

```
application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.text
```

In your web.config file you need to add inside `system.webServer` section:

```
<staticContent>
    <remove fileExtension=".odt" />
    <mimeMap fileExtension=".odt" mimeType="application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.text" />
</staticContent>
```

Comment: hello, thanks you i have solved the problem by adding the mime type directly on IIS. So with your answer, i will add on the web config. It's more safe. Thanks

Comment: Your question was titled ASP, if I had seen the .NET tag I would have also mentioned this.